# Failed to upgrade database: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, desktop

i receive below message when trying to upgrade from neo4j 3.5.2 tot 3.5.3 in the desktop: Failed to upgrade database: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\xxx\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-ffca7d5a-b65a-45b9-ab6d-3c15cc302390\installation-3.5.3\data'

I tried it with and without a database with same result.. i did not check the auto migrate datastore option and my conf file allows auto upgrade from prev versions .. also removed plugins and tried again with same result..

Any clues ?

Thanks Koen

Comment: so to answer my own question .. i learned through github that will be fixed in a desktop update coming out soon.. thanks

Comment: I just installed the latest version of the desktop in which this issues was fixed and upgraded smoothly to 3.5.3. reg koen